# How to MultiLine EditText with the cursor with the padding starting on top?

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, padding

I am using `EditText` for message. Padding of `EditText` is `30sdp`.

Problem is that when i click on this EditText, cursor is blinking on the middle of the EditText,while I want cursor should be blink in the top of the EditText.

This is my code.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edremarkspetrolbill"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvpetrolbillremarks"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_boxsearch"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorbluewh"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorbluewh" />
```

Comment: Please provide your XML snippet.

Comment: Padding is internal spacing. You're telling the `EditText` to shift all of its content inward by 30, on every side. That includes the text lines, and the cursor. If you don't want that padding on top, then remove the `padding` attribute, and set the other three individually; i.e., paddingLeft, `paddingRight`, and `paddingBottom`.

Answer (score 2):

set gravity to top in multiline edittext

```
android:gravity="top"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use gravity like below

```
android:gravity="top|left"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: You have only use gravity :"top" .  use it as mentioned in my answer -> "top|left"

Answer (score 0):

add  this attribute in your edittext: `android:gravity="top"`

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity="top"` is correct, but you have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and it is problem. Your edit text height is near your text size + paddings and cursor is in the top of edit text, but you can not see it. If you set height to your edit text more then now, you will see where cursor is. Or if you want height `wrap_content`, you can provide `minHeight` param, then edit text will be inflated with `minHeight` and will expand if the text does not fit it height. You can also provide not only one parameter in `gravity` field, just append params with `|`. For example: `top|start`, `top|end`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code like this ( I 've put 100dp as height but I suggest you to put the EditText in a CostraintLayout and use match_constraint)

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edremarkspetrolbill"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvpetrolbillremarks"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_boxsearch"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/colorbluewh"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorbluewh" />
```

Comment: thank you for me suggestion,but sorry to you say all method apply but not solve my problem and can not use constraintLayout.

Comment: did you try my xml?

Comment: Yes.try to your xml only you modified layout_height.but sorry not work .

Comment: and removed padding thats why i told you to copy and paste it :)